# Using Symfony1 security structure in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony1

i am having an big application developed in symfony1 with different modules.
Now i developed some new modules in symfony2.

Authentication is used in the modules (symfony1) with username and password.
I want to authenticate within the symfony2 modules with the username and password from the database in symfony1.

How do i make this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have connection to the symfony1 database?

Comment: yes i have connection

Comment: Then you can query the database, right? You can even make compatible models.